# input of any numerical value and sort in go1.5.2

Tags: go

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)
```

Confirm any numerical value here.

```
func go_input(){
    var N,i,j int
    var A =[]int{100}

    fmt.Scanf("%d",&N)

    for i:= 0;  i < N; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d",&A[i])
    }
}
```

Sort a value here.but,An error is given.

```
func i_Sort(){
    sort.Sort(go_input())
    fmt.Println(go_input())
}
```

Execute it here.

```
func main(){
    i_Sort()
}
```

go 1.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go_input()` doesn't return a value, so you can't use it in `fmt.Println`

More importantly, you are creating a brand new array every time you call `go_input()`, maybe you want to return a value and then reuse that?

`sort.Ints()` is the function you want for sorting a slice anyways

With some small changes, you need something like this:
http://play.golang.org/p/MhOlRNCIwI

Comment: your answer is acceptable, but you'd better put some code samples for the OP to understand.

Comment: Thank you.You are an extremely kind person.